# xgboost.cv TypeError: cv() got multiple values for argument 'dtrain'

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, decision-tree

Im trying to manually test different hyperparameters for xgboost, but this error keeps coming. I'm not sure how im supplying multiple arguments to dtrain if it ends with a comma.

```
import xgboost as xgb
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X, label=y)
params = {'eta':[0.1]}
xgb_cv = xgb.cv(
    {'disable_default_eval_metric': 1},
    params,
    dtrain=dtrain,
    seed=1,
    nfold=5,
    custom_metric=f1_score
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature for `xgboost.cv` is `(params, dtrain, ...)`.  So it thinks you're passing the metric-disabling-dict as `params`, the eta-dict as `dtrain`, and then trying to pass another `dtrain` by keyword.  If `disable_default_eval_metric` is supposed to be another parameter, add it to the `params` dictionary that contains `eta` instead.